# Сгруппировать данные (GroupBy) по некоторому признаку и сохранить результаты в новые таблицы

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, group-by

Надо сгруппировать данные (`GroupBy`) по некоторому признаку и сохранить результаты в новые таблицы.

Для каждой новой таблицы провести сортировку по сложному ключу, состоящему из нескольких признаков. Для каждой таблицы своя сортировка.

У меня есть некий [набор данных](https://www.kaggle.com/neuromusic/avocado-prices). Хочу сгруппировать данные по годам. Получилось только:

```py
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('year')))
print (dfs[2015])
print (dfs[2016])
print (dfs[2017])
print (dfs[2018])
```

Не совсем понимаю, что нужно сделать дальше.

Comment: мы тоже не понимаем - данных нет, признаков сортировки нет. что делать, ума не приложим просто....

Comment: Ссылка на данные: https://www.kaggle.com/neuromusic/avocado-prices

Comment: На StackOverflow принято задавать один конкретный вопрос, который вы пытались самостоятельно решить и не смогли. В текущем виде - это не вопрос, а задание, состоящее из нескольких вопросов. Разбейте задачу на модули и решайте их постепенно. Если возникнет проблема с конкретным шагом - задайте здесь соответствующий вопрос и мы вам поможем ;)

Comment: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Поставил плюс только как аванс. Пожалуйста, не сочтите за труд ознакомтся с комментариями выше.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на первый вопрос:

> Сгруппировать данные (GroupBy) по некоторому признаку и сохранить
>   результаты в новые таблицы

читаем CSV:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\avocado.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=["Date"])
```

создаем словарь DataFrame'ов:

```
dfs = {key:data for key, data in df.groupby("year")}
```

---

результат:

```
In [12]: dfs.keys()
Out[12]: dict_keys([2015, 2016, 2017, 2018])

In [13]: dfs[2015]
Out[13]:
         Date  AveragePrice  Total Volume     4046  ...  XLarge Bags          type  year            region
0  2015-12-27          1.33      64236.62  1036.74  ...          0.0  conventional  2015            Albany
1  2015-12-20          1.35      54876.98   674.28  ...          0.0  conventional  2015            Albany
2  2015-12-13          0.93     118220.22   794.70  ...          0.0  conventional  2015            Albany
3  2015-12-06          1.08      78992.15  1132.00  ...          0.0  conventional  2015            Albany
4  2015-11-29          1.28      51039.60   941.48  ...          0.0  conventional  2015            Albany
..        ...           ...           ...      ...  ...          ...           ...   ...               ...
46 2015-02-01          1.77       7210.19  1634.42  ...          0.0       organic  2015  WestTexNewMexico
47 2015-01-25          1.63       7324.06  1934.46  ...          0.0       organic  2015  WestTexNewMexico
48 2015-01-18          1.71       5508.20  1793.64  ...          0.0       organic  2015  WestTexNewMexico
49 2015-01-11          1.69       6861.73  1822.28  ...          0.0       organic  2015  WestTexNewMexico
50 2015-01-04          1.64       6182.81  1561.30  ...          0.0       organic  2015  WestTexNewMexico

[5615 rows x 13 columns]

In [14]: dfs[2018]
Out[14]:
         Date  AveragePrice  Total Volume      4046  ...  XLarge Bags          type  year            region
0  2018-03-25          1.57     149396.50  16361.69  ...       380.00  conventional  2018            Albany
1  2018-03-18          1.35     105304.65  13234.86  ...       500.00  conventional  2018            Albany
2  2018-03-11          1.12     144648.75  15823.35  ...       291.11  conventional  2018            Albany
3  2018-03-04          1.08     139520.60  12002.12  ...       283.33  conventional  2018            Albany
4  2018-02-25          1.28     104278.89  10368.77  ...       310.00  conventional  2018            Albany
..        ...           ...           ...       ...  ...          ...           ...   ...               ...
7  2018-02-04          1.63      17074.83   2046.96  ...         0.00       organic  2018  WestTexNewMexico
8  2018-01-28          1.71      13888.04   1191.70  ...         0.00       organic  2018  WestTexNewMexico
9  2018-01-21          1.87      13766.76   1191.92  ...         0.00       organic  2018  WestTexNewMexico
10 2018-01-14          1.93      16205.22   1527.63  ...         0.00       organic  2018  WestTexNewMexico
11 2018-01-07          1.62      17489.58   2894.77  ...         0.00       organic  2018  WestTexNewMexico

[1296 rows x 13 columns]
```

---

PS чтобы получить ответы на остальные вопросы - задайте пожалуйста новые вопросы [в соответствии с правилами SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).